# Can not get post data

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, request

I'm trying to get post data into my controller.

It tells me that `Request.Form` does not exists, any ideas how I then get the post data for my application?

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class Car
    Public Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal iName As String)
        Name = iName
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class CarController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function PostCar() As Car
        Return New Car(Request.Form["name"])
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You are using `asp.net` correct?

Comment: Thats correct @zaggler

Comment: Are you developing MVC application or web form application?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri A MVC application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code,

```
Public Class CarController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function PostCar() As Car
        Return New Car(Request.Form("name"))
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This throws an error `'Form' is not a member of 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage'.`. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("name")`. Thanks.